# Microsoft WebDriver installation issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting an error while installing the MicrosoftWebDriver as mentioned below:

> "The version of web browser is not supported for MicrosoftWebDriver"

I downloaded the MicrosoftWebDriver from Release 10586 and checked the Version of my browser and its 13.10586 but still not able to install.